# Pandas read_csv() not assigning to variable within function

Tags: python, csv

I'm using the below code to assign the content of a `csv` to a variable:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Book1.csv", header='infer',  encoding="ISO-8859+-1")
```

I'd like to condense this in a function like so:

```
def loader(x, y):
    x = pd.read_csv(y, header='infer',  encoding="ISO-8859+-1")
```

However, the above function doesn't seem to be assigning the `csv` to the given value of `x`?

I'm relatively new to Python and have been searching for a solution for a few hours - no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python always passes by reference, so what you are trying to do won't work in general.  Instead try:

```
def loader(y):
    return pd.read_csv(y, header='infer',  encoding="ISO-8859+-1")

x = loader("Book1.csv")
```

This returns the dataframe from the function and assigns it to a variable named `x`.